# Should I trust the significant results of a glm or the post hoc analyses with no significance across the variables?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

GLM analyses are new to me so please excuse my ignorance in advance. I want to see if the number of road crossings differ across years for a specific taxa. I am working in RStudio and have found my `glm` to identify years as an influential factor, yet when I run a post hoc anaylsis there is no significant difference among any of the year combinations. I identified my family for the `glm` as a `quasipoisson`. My `glm` code reads as:

```
yrrxglm <- glm(yrrxdata$RX~as.factor(yrrxdata$YEAR)-1*yrrxdata$ID, family=quasipoisson)
```

- `RX` is the number of crossings
- `Year` is the factor I want to identify as having an impact or not on the crossings
- `ID` is the ID number for the individuals (as some have more crossings than others)

My results for this model are:

```
glm(formula = yrrxdata$RX ~ as.factor(yrrxdata$YEAR) - 1 * yrrxdata$ID, 
    family = quasipoisson)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-5.957  -3.393  -1.449   1.260  11.466  

Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
as.factor(yrrxdata$YEAR)2009   1.9924     0.6080   3.277  0.00129 ** 
as.factor(yrrxdata$YEAR)2010   2.5802     0.2482  10.394  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(yrrxdata$YEAR)2011   2.2824     0.3327   6.861 1.49e-10 ***
as.factor(yrrxdata$YEAR)2012   1.1527     0.9253   1.246  0.21472    
as.factor(yrrxdata$YEAR)2013   2.5246     0.1876  13.454  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(yrrxdata$YEAR)2014   2.8761     0.1460  19.697  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(yrrxdata$YEAR)2015   2.6525     0.1760  15.070  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(yrrxdata$YEAR)2016   0.0000     4.0333   0.000  1.00000    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasipoisson family taken to be 16.26731)

    Null deviance: 9912.4  on 165  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2273.2  on 157  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

I then ran a post hoc test to see which years were significantly different from one another and received these results:

```
     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: glm(formula = yrrxdata$RX ~ as.factor(yrrxdata$YEAR) - 1 * yrrxdata$PUFF_ADDER, 
    family = quasipoisson)

Linear Hypotheses:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
2010 - 2009 == 0  0.58779    0.65676   0.895    0.980
2011 - 2009 == 0  0.28995    0.69309   0.418    1.000
2012 - 2009 == 0 -0.83975    1.10720  -0.758    0.993
2013 - 2009 == 0  0.53222    0.63633   0.836    0.987
2014 - 2009 == 0  0.88363    0.62533   1.413    0.807
2015 - 2009 == 0  0.66005    0.63300   1.043    0.954
2016 - 2009 == 0 -1.99243    4.07885  -0.488    1.000
2011 - 2010 == 0 -0.29783    0.41507  -0.718    0.995
2012 - 2010 == 0 -1.42754    0.95801  -1.490    0.761
2013 - 2010 == 0 -0.05557    0.31117  -0.179    1.000
2014 - 2010 == 0  0.29584    0.28799   1.027    0.958
2015 - 2010 == 0  0.07226    0.30430   0.237    1.000
2016 - 2010 == 0 -2.58022    4.04091  -0.639    0.997
2012 - 2011 == 0 -1.12970    0.98328  -1.149    0.925
2013 - 2011 == 0  0.24226    0.38193   0.634    0.998
2014 - 2011 == 0  0.59368    0.36329   1.634    0.666
2015 - 2011 == 0  0.37010    0.37636   0.983    0.967
2016 - 2011 == 0 -2.28238    4.04697  -0.564    0.999
2013 - 2012 == 0  1.37197    0.94413   1.453    0.783
2014 - 2012 == 0  1.72338    0.93675   1.840    0.519
2015 - 2012 == 0  1.49980    0.94189   1.592    0.694
2016 - 2012 == 0 -1.15268    4.13805  -0.279    1.000
2014 - 2013 == 0  0.35141    0.23776   1.478    0.768
2015 - 2013 == 0  0.12783    0.25728   0.497    0.999
2016 - 2013 == 0 -2.52465    4.03764  -0.625    0.998
2015 - 2014 == 0 -0.22358    0.22869  -0.978    0.968
2016 - 2014 == 0 -2.87606    4.03592  -0.713    0.995
2016 - 2015 == 0 -2.65248    4.03711  -0.657    0.997
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)

Warning message:
In RET$pfunction("adjusted", ...) : Completion with error > abseps
```

Yet no differences are shown across years in the post hoc. When I run this test for other variables such as sex or season or road type the post hoc corresponds to the glm. How is it that I can contrasting results? Or am I interpreting the outputs incorrectly?

I have now run a Fisher's LSD test and am viewing another 'contradictory' result:

```
> lsd <- LSD.test(yrrxglm, "as.factor(YEAR)", console=TRUE)

Study: yrrxglm ~ "as.factor(YEAR)"

LSD t Test for RX.M 

Mean Square Error:  2.188433 

as.factor(YEAR),  means and individual ( 95 %) CI

         RX.M       std  r       LCL      UCL  Min      Max
2009 2.290000 0.6308724  5 0.9824162 3.597584 1.50  3.00000
2010 3.178155 2.1253993 20 2.5243629 3.831947 1.00 10.25000
2011 3.716667 2.4730291 15 2.9617328 4.471601 1.25  8.50000
2012 2.583333 1.9083151  6 1.3896781 3.776989 1.00  6.00000
2013 4.152020 3.6338607 33 3.6430439 4.660997 1.00 16.00000
2014 4.599847 3.3134289 39 4.1316573 5.068037 1.00 12.33333
2015 4.199720 3.7452463 34 3.6982844 4.701155 1.00 15.20000

Alpha: 0.05 ; DF Error: 145
Critical Value of t: 1.97646 

Groups according to probability of means differences and alpha level( 0.05 )

Treatments with the same letter are not significantly different.

         RX.M groups
2014 4.599847      a
2015 4.199720      a
2013 4.152020      a
2011 3.716667     ab
2010 3.178155      b
2012 2.583333      b
2009 2.290000      b
```

The Fisher's LSD test is saying that 2011 is different to other years. But the graph doesn't seem to show any year as different.

[image: number of crossings on the y axis and year on the x axis]

Answer (score 1):

Note the term 'simultaneous tests'  in the `glht` output. This means that the p values are adjusted for multiplicity (in this case, a family of 28 hypothesis tests). Such an adjustment is done to control the probability of making a type I error *anywhere* among those 28 tests. That makes them a lot more conservative.